# The random question generator is only prompting 1 question in the array of objects, and exiting the prompt. Instead prompting all the questions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

- I created an array of objects, and it randomly picks a question out of 1 of the objects and puts in in a prompt box.
- But, its only prompting 1 question, and it breaks out the prompt box.  It doesn't prompt all the other questions 1 after another.

```
let theQuestions = [

     {
        question: "What is the capital of Georgia?", 
        answer:     "atlanta"
     },

     {
        question: "What is the name of the Atlanta Baseball Team?", 
        answer:   "atlanta braves"
     },

     {
        question: "How many rings have the Atlanta Falcons Won?", 
        answer:   0
     },

     {
        question: "What is the name of the NBA team in Miami?", 
        answer:   "miami heat"
     }

];// theQuestions array

const randomQuestions = ()=>{
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() *theQuestions.length);
  return theQuestions[random];

}// randomQuestions



let question = randomQuestions().question;
let answer  = randomQuestions().answer;


const askQuestions = prompt(question);
```

Comment: A loop could help. And maybe not calling the function again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask all questions in a row you need some kind of loop.
Here is an example with a while loop.

This piece in you code wont work anyway because you wont get the right answer most of the times:

```
let question = randomQuestions().question;
let answer  = randomQuestions().answer;
```

If you wan't to ask the questions in a random order you need an indicator which question was already asked. A simple idea is to just remove the asked question from the array.

```js
let theQuestions = [
  { question: "What is the capital of Georgia?", answer: "atlanta" },
  { question: "What is the name of the Atlanta Baseball Team?", answer: "atlanta braves" },
  { question: "How many rings have the Atlanta Falcons Won?", answer: 0 },
  { question: "What is the name of the NBA team in Miami?", answer: "miami heat" }
];

const randomQuestions = () => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * theQuestions.length);
  const question = theQuestions.splice(index, 1);
  return question[0];

}

while(theQuestions.length) {
  const question = randomQuestions();
  const askedQuestion = prompt(question.question);
  if (askedQuestion === null) {
    console.log("User clicked cancel");
  } else {
    console.log(askedQuestion.toLowerCase() === question.answer);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you , I appreciate that.  How would I get the answers as well, out as well in the while loop?  I can do this in a for loop but not in a while loop.

Comment: @myko Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, you can access the answer through `question.answer`